# Reverse for 'showuser' with keyword arguments '{'bid': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['showuser/(?P<broadcastid>[0-9]+)\\Z']

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am getting the following error:

> Reverse for 'showuser' with keyword arguments '{'bid': 1}' not found.
> 1 pattern(s) tried: ['showuser/(?P[0-9]+)\Z']

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

`urls.py:`

```
 path('showuser/<int:broadcastid>', views.showuser, name="showuser")
```

`views.py:`

```
def showuser(request, broadcastid):
  vrbrlstnm = BroadcastListSms.objects.get(id=broadcastid)
  showDepartment = AddContact.objects.values('dept_nm').distinct()
  if request.method == "GET":
    if request.GET.get('select') == "All":
        departmentData = AddContact.objects.all()
    else:
        departmentData = AddContact.objects.filter(dept_nm=request.GET.get('select'))
    return render(request, "showuser.html", {'adduser': vrbrlstnm, 'showDepartment': showDepartment, 'departmentData': departmentData})
  return HttpResponseRedirect("showuser", {'showDepartment': showDepartment, 'departmentData': departmentData})
```

`adduser.html`

```
  <a href="{% url 'showuser' int:broadcastid=adduser.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Existing User
  </a>
```

`Note: adduser.id is the foreign key value, from where we get broadcastid.`
I am stuck here from so many days. Not able to understand what to do now.

```
class BroadcastListSms(models.Model):
  brl_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

class AddContact(models.Model):
  f_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
  l_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
  broadcast_list = models.ForeignKey(BroadcastListSms, 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='adduser', null=True)
```

`Note: BroadcastListSms is master table, and displaying data that are in the particular broadcast list wise.`

Screenshot of error:
[image]

[Data files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r_pW7TvHLrZdb-TJ4j2PYr8fCoOEcHq2/view)

Comment: The parameter in the url pattern is named `broadcastid` not `bid`

Comment: Yes, that is already changed, but still the error is same.

Comment: What is already changed? Your url tag should contain `broadcastid=adduser.id` not `bid=adduser.id`

Comment: As per your comment I tried and change my code but still error remains same.

Comment: @HellySoni Try `href="{% url 'showuser' adduser.id %}"` only in anchor tag and try adding slash `/` at the end of path as ` path('showuser/<int:broadcastid>/'....`

Comment: Can you share your `BroadcastListSms` model? And also where you are handling the view for the `POST` condition? You have only handled it for `GET` condition, the last option is to share your GitHub repo.

Comment: @SunderamDubey BroadcastListSms is master table . I share both table model details in my original Question. Please check.

Comment: Where did you share? Can you share GitHub repo?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I just share models here in Question.

Comment: Can you please also share the view which is rendering the instance `adduser` in adduser.html?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I have already share adduser.html code.

Comment: I am talking about the view which is rendering `adduser.html`, the view from which `adduser` is passing in the template, then you are sending  in url `showuser` as `adduser.id`. Last option to share your GitHub repo, otherwise I can't help bye :)

Comment: @SunderamDubey I have attached link in Question. You can check that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245960/discussion-between-helly-soni-and-sunderam-dubey).

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify `int:`, the `<int:…>` part is *not* part of the variable name, but the [*path converter* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters). The name of the parameter is thus `broadcastid`:

```
<a href="{% url 'showuser' broadcastid=adduser.id %}" … >
    …
</a>
```

Comment: After removing <int:> from urls.py error is like this:  =====  
Reverse for 'showuser' with keyword arguments '{'broadcastid': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['showuser/(?P<broadcastid>[^/]+)\\Z']

Comment: @HellySoni: you should *not* remove the `<int:...>` from the `urls.py`. Furthermore it looks like somehow there is no `adduser` in the context when you render the template...

Comment: No, I checked. I got valid value in adduser context.

Comment: @HellySoni: the empty string `''` in `{'broadcastid': ''}` means that `adduser.id` resolved to the empty string, wich is often because the variable did not exist. Note that this is where you rendered `adduser.html`, not `showuser.html`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sir willem simply do this `{% url 'showuser' adduser.id %}`  and say to add `/` at the end of every route as `path('showuser/<int:broadcastid>/'....`. Edit your answer.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I tried both way, but still the error is same.  I attach screenshot in my question.